# Applying two middlewares to a route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to apply two middlewares to some routes in Laravel.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ('auth_guest'), 'prefix' => 'guest/'], function() {
    //  60 routes
});
```

I know two solutions:

1- Apply the middleware on the controller's constructor.

2- Combine both middlewares and make it one.

Although both would work I would like to keep both middlewares separated.

Is there a way to apply both middlewares in a group?

Something like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ('auth_guest'), 'prefix' => 'guest/'], function() {

Route::group(['middleware' => ('isgreat')], function() {
//60 routes
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can apply a list of middlewares like this:

```
Route::middleware(['auth',RegionLock::class,CampaignStarted::class, UserBanned::class])
->group(function () {
...
});
```

or a group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['first','second']], function () {
    //
});
```

[DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware):

You may also assign multiple middleware to the route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    //
})->middleware('first', 'second');
```